# In SQL how can I repeat Row_Number value after a count of 3?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has 1000 rows. And I want to add a new column with the Row_number that repeats after a count of 3

INPUT TABLE

| ID | Name | CountryCode | District | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kabul | Afg | Kabol | 178000 |
| 2 | Qandahar | Afg | Qandahar | 237500 |
| 3 | Herat | Afg | Herat | 186800 |
| 4 | Mazar-e-Sharif | Afg | Balkh | 127800 |
| 5 | Amsterdam | Nld | Noord-Holland | 731200 |
| 6 | Rotterdam | Nld | Zuid-Holland | 593321 |
| 7 | Haag | Nld | Zuid-Holland | 440900 |
| 8 | Utrecht | Nld | Utrecht | 234323 |
| 9 | Eindhoven | Nld | Noord-Brabant | 201843 |
| 10 | Tilburg | Nld | Noord-Brabant | 193238 |
| 11 | Groningen | Nld | Groningen | 172701 |

OUTPUT TABLE

| ID | Name | CountryCode | District | Population | Row_Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kabul | Afg | Kabol | 178000 | 1 |
| 2 | Qandahar | Afg | Qandahar | 237500 | 2 |
| 3 | Herat | Afg | Herat | 186800 | 3 |
| 4 | Mazar-e-Sharif | Afg | Balkh | 127800 | 1 |
| 5 | Amsterdam | Nld | Noord-Holland | 731200 | 2 |
| 6 | Rotterdam | Nld | Zuid-Holland | 593321 | 3 |
| 7 | Haag | Nld | Zuid-Holland | 440900 | 1 |
| 8 | Utrecht | Nld | Utrecht | 234323 | 2 |
| 9 | Eindhoven | Nld | Noord-Brabant | 201843 | 3 |
| 10 | Tilburg | Nld | Noord-Brabant | 193238 | 1 |
| 11 | Groningen | Nld | Groningen | 172701 | 2 |

Comment: you need to show your attempt

Comment: maybe `replace(((row_number() OVER ()) mod 3), 0, 3)`

Comment: You can use the [modulo operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod) for this, e.g. `1 + ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 1) % 3)`

Comment: @GarethD silly question: why the +1 -1 trick?

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: @dcolazin for the 3rd row you get `3 % 3` which yields 0, and not 3 as required, so ideally we want `mod  + 1` to ensure results in the range of 1-3 rather than 0-2, but to then get this to work starting at 1, we also need to minus 1 from the RowNumber to ensure that this starts at 0 rather than 1. [Example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wMQEdwrBBoCA8Sc1jurSFp/0)

Comment: @GarethD yeah, it was a silly question :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ROW_NUMBER() to get a row number, you can the use various ways to get it to be 1,2,3 in a sequence, for instance use modulus

`case when MOD(ROW_NUMBER(),3) = 0 then 3 else MOD(ROW_NUMBER(),3) end as row_number`.

Answer (score 0):

`select *,((ROW_NUMBER() OVER () -1) % 3) + 1 as "row_number" from table;`